# Error message when trying to convert private key from a pem-file to a pvk-file

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to convert a private key from a pem file/format to a pvk file/format using OpenSSL with the following command:

```
openssl rsa -in C:\tmp\key.pem -outform PVK -pvk-strong -out C:\tmp\key.pvk
```

I get the following error message after entering the PEM pass phrase (for test purposes I'm using a 4 letter strong pass phrase as far as I understand 4 characters is minimum):

```
unable to write key
22164:error:060A6094:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptUpdate:invalid operation:crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:451:
```

Couldn't really find any information on how to resolve the error, any pointers would be appreciated.

Note: the private key was extracted from an pfx file which triggered a warning, please see my [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1531661/export-private-key-from-pfx-file-warning-unsupported-bag-type-secretbag)

Note: there are various guides for this conversion (e.g. [this one](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/comodo/Knowledgebase/Article/View/548/7/))

Comment: I'm not 100% on this- I've done minimal work issuing self-signed certs from an in-house certificate authority running openSSL... but I'm not sure you can go from .pem to .pvk. Try converting your .pfx file into .pvk. Some more info on what it is you're doing and what you're trying to accomplish? Do you have the associated .csr, .ext, .key, .pfx files to work with?

Comment: @boog I extracted the private key from a pfx file (used for code signing) and need to create another pfx file with a new certificate. Not sure if the conversion works, but there are various guides that show you how, but maybe i overlooked s.th.. Is it possible to extract a private key form a pfx file directly (using OpenSSL)? That might be a solution

Answer (score 1):

So, have you tried first converting your .pem to a .crt, converting that .crt to .pvk?

Convert .pem to .crt:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in your-cert.pem -out your-cert.crt
```

Convert .crt to .pvk:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out name_of_cert.pfx -inkey name_of_key.key -in 
name_of_cert.crt
```

Comment: Thanks, you got it more or less right, except I'm using an "outside" CA (digicert) to issue the certificate (which is used for code signing). The new certificate was created using an existing CSR (I know this is not best practice) to which I don't have the private key. But I do have a PFX that was created with another certificate so I extracted the private key using OpenSSL (creating key.pem). Now I need to create a new .pfx from the new certificate issued by digicert and key.pem. To do this I wanted to convert key.pem into key.pvk.

Comment: @Albin - in case you haven't figured this out yet- see my edit at the end of my previous answer. Have you tried converting first from .pem to .crt, then .crt to .pvk?

Comment: not yet, I'll let you know if it worked