# export private key from pfx-file (Warning unsupported bag type: secretBag)

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to export a private key from a pfx-file using OpenSSL:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in C:\tmp\pfxfile.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out C:\tmp\prvkey.pem
```

I get the prompt to enter the password:

```
Enter Import Password:
```

upon entering a files gets created but I get the following error message:

```
Warning unsupported bag type: secretBag
```

I tried some research, but I couldn't find out if the warning poses a problem. The final goal is to create a pvk file for the private key which fails with a error message - please see my [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1531660/error-message-when-trying-to-convert-private-key-from-a-pem-file-to-a-pvk-file).

Here's the content of `prvkey.pem`:

```
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    friendlyName: **-********-****-****-****-************
    Microsoft CSP Name: Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0
Key Attributes
    X509v3 Key Usage: 80 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
************************
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: @garethTheRed The certificate was issued by digicert, it's for code signing. I had had to reissue a new certificate quickly because the old certificate was already expired, so I just used the same CSR-string/file to create the new certificate. Now I need to create a new pfx-file with the new certificate. Do do that I need the private key, which I could export from the pfx-file from the old certificate.

Comment: What does the final file look like?  Obviously don't paste it here, but does it begin with `----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and end with `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`?  Can you view it with `openssl rsa -in prvkey.pem -noout -text` and/or verify it with `openssl rsa -in prvkey.pem -noout -check`?

Comment: @garethTheRed I put the content into my question, as far as I know that's how it's suppose to look like. Maybe there is another way to test if the key has been exported correctly?

Comment: @garethTheRed Not yet. I assume I should verify the "old" pfx with my exported private key?

Comment: The command simply verifies that the RSA private key is valid after you have generated it.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error and this worked for me:
During the export through the Windows MMC uncheck all options to extra secure the PKCS#12
.Also be sure that you are not selecting a user or group (in the next window) Choose a password instead.